# Endpoint / API Key for Microsoft Academic Knowledge

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the MS Academic Knowledge API. I signed up for keys here as per the docs
https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-US/sign-up

When I use the key I get errors as follows

api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com:

Endpoint api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com is not supported

westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com:

'Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key.'

I'm not sure what is going on here and which endpoint I need to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/interpret?query=darrin%20eid&complete=1&count=10&model=latest&subscription-key=your_key

(replace "your_key" with your labs subscription key)

Additionally, you can see the URL you need to use for each different API when you use the ["try it" test site](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/56332331778daf06340c9666/console)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was using node-cognitive-services npm package which was restricting the enpoint to westus. Have now submitted a pull request to add labs